# Creating VM in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently I started to use Azure.
In Azure, I created Resources Group, Virtual Network, Availability Set and Virtual Machine.
Then I connected VM using RDP

Same way, I want to create and connect VM in AWS.
Please let me know, what steps I need to follow.

Comment: First step. Read the documentation on AWS' website. AWS has written several good tutorials. Pick one and practice.

Comment: do you want to connect Azure VM with an EC2 instance? I think you need to provide more info.

Comment: Almost all tutorials are initially descriptive with various terminologies and topics. As an introductory start-up in Azure, I know only how to create a VM and how to connect it using RDP but I am going through its tutorials step-by-step for various topics and terminologies. Same way, as an introductory start-up in AWS, I want to know how to create a VM and how to connect it.

Comment: No I don’t want to connect Azure VM to EC2 instance. I want steps so that I can create a VM on AWS and connect it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Machines on AWS are provided by the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud service, more commonly known as **Amazon EC2**. Individual VMs are referred to as **instances**. Thus, the terminology to seek is "Amazon EC2 instance".

There are many ways to launch an Amazon EC2 instance, such as using a web interface, making an API call or using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

See: [Launch Your Instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/LaunchingAndUsingInstances.html)

To launch an instance from the EC2 management console, click **Launch instance** and provide the desired configuration.

See: [Launching an Instance Using the Launch Instance Wizard - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html)